# Other than Arnold Schwarzenegger, was anyone from T1 and T2 involved in making Genisys?

Tags: terminator-genisys, terminator-series, the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day, crew

In my opinion *Terminator: Genysis* was much closer to the likes of *Transformers* than either *T1* or *T2*, so I was wondering if anyone other than Arnold schwarzenegger was involved with all 3 movies: *T1*, *T2* and *Genysis*.

And just to clarify a bit, by closer to the likes of *Transformers* than either *T1* or *T2*, I mean it was made for children, loads of jokes and gags, was pretty much a *Twilight* love story with a sci-fi movie wrapped around it and overall was just pretty poor.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can look at the IMDb pages to see who wrote/directed/produced the projects.

Comment: You don't understand the question but you gave me a helpful bit of advice nonetheless 

Comment: I like this question but it looks like it's getting DVs. Delete the body and put the word *actors* in the title. There were plenty of cameos in the second movie -I don't think anyone else who was acting in 1984 was worth the effort in 2015.

Comment: @Mazura actually that's a very good point. I never really considered the age of the cast and crew.

Comment: [This blog](http://io9.com/all-the-details-you-might-have-missed-in-the-terminator-1666899042) was fun to read. Look at how totally ripped he was. Dude *was* a machine. I'll admit though, that I never knew 1L19 was in #2; didn't look like the same kid. I'd love to know of some easter egg in #5, but I don't think there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMDB's [common cast/crew search](http://www.imdb.com/search/common) indicates a number of people who were involved in one or both of the original two films and the most recent:

- **Arnold Schwarzenegger** (obviously)

and

- **Joel Kramer** - Stunt Dept
- **Ethan Van der Ryn** - Sound Dept
- **Carl Miller** - Visual Effects
- **Harry Lu**  - Stunts
- **Martin J. Gibbons** - Art Department
- **Robert Misetich** - Art Department

The credits for Genisys also mention

- **Gale Anne Hurd** - As "Character Consultant"
- **James Cameron** - As "Character Consultant"